# ng-repeat nested inside Popover not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have the following ng-repeat list:

```
<div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in recordlist 
     people-popover>
       <div class="col-md-1 msf-centered" ng-show="editItem == false" ng-hide="editItem"> 
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control msf-paxlist" 
                  rel="popover" 
                  data-content="<li ng-repeat='passanger in record.pax'>
                                   {{passanger.name}}
                                </li>" 
                  data-original-title="Passanger List">
              {{record.pax.length}} <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          </button>
       </div>
</div>
```

I initialize the popover with a directive:

```
.directive('peoplePopover', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.find("button[rel=popover]").popover({ placement: 'bottom', html: 'true'});
    };
})
```

The problem is the `<li ng-repeat="pasanger in record.pax">{{pasanger.name}}</li>`, which will not show.

If I use `<li ng-repeat="record.pax">{{pax}}</li>`, it will display the array, but if I try to list the objects of the array with ng-repeat, it won't work.

This is how the array (record) looks like:

```
record in recordlist {
    date : "02/12/2014"
    time : "00.02.01"
    car : "369"
    pax: [
        {
        name : "Ben"
        chosen : true
        },
        {
        name : "Eric"
        chosen : true
        }
    ]
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Could you include the structure of the array you want displayed?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just to confirm - is `recordlist` an object or array?

Comment: Array, the code above is an object (record) from recordlist (array)

Comment: Have the same issue! Looks like ng-repeat inside data-content isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into similar problem and I solved it this way.

I wrapped the ng-repeat block in another directive and pass the collection to that external directive.

```
div class="row msf-row" 
     ng-repeat="record in recordlist 
     people-popover>
       <div class="col-md-1 msf-centered" ng-show="editItem == false" ng-hide="editItem"> 
          <button class="btn btn-primary form-control msf-paxlist" 
                  rel="popover" 
                  data-content="<new-directive records=record.pax></new-directive>" 
                  data-original-title="Passanger List">
              {{record.pax.length}} <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          </button>
       </div>
</div>
```

Inside the new directive, you will have this code.

```
<li ng-repeat='passanger in record.pax'>
         {{passanger.name}}
</li>
```

Hopefully this helps someone who runs into similar problem.

Comment: i am trying this but i cant get it working. could you post your whole directive ?